Phonepe sdk integration flutter
While integrating phonepe_payment_sdk, its shows an error
Its working fine on testkit, but shows error on production
key_error_result:{"success":false,"code":"INVALID_TRANSACTION_ID","message":"The transaction id you have entered seems to be invalid.","data":{}}
Solve error of phonepe_payment_sdk
    import 'package:phonepe_payment_sdk/phonepe_payment_sdk.dart';

Object? result;

class PaymentUtility {
  static Future<void> initPhonePeSdk(
      String merchentID, Function(void Function()) setState) async {
        print("merchentID------$merchentID");
        //PRODUCTION
        // SANDBOX
    await PhonePePaymentSdk.init('PRODUCTION', 'com.abc,abc', merchentID, true)
        .then((isInitialized) => {
              setState(() {
                result = 'PhonePe SDK Initialized - $isInitialized';
              })
            })
        .catchError((error) {
      handleError(error, setState);
      return <dynamic>{};
    });
  }

  static Future<void> startTransaction(
      String body, String checkSum, Function(void Function()) setState) async {
    try {
      // com.phonepe.app
      // com.phonepe.simulator
      await PhonePePaymentSdk.startTransaction(
              body, '', checkSum, 'com.phonepe.app')
          .then((response) => {
                setState(() {
                  print(response);
                  if (response != null) {
                    String status = response['status'].toString();
                    String error = response['error'].toString();
                    if (status == 'SUCCESS') {
                      result = "Flow Completed - Status: Success!";
                    } else {
                      result =
                          "Flow Completed - Status: $status and Error: $error";
                    }
                  } else {
                    result = "Flow Incomplete";
                  }
                })
              })
          .catchError((error) {
        handleError(error, setState);
        return <dynamic>{};
      });
    } catch (error) {
      handleError(error, setState);
    }
  }

  static void handleError(dynamic error, Function(void Function()) setState) {
    setState(() {
      if (error is Exception) {
        result = error.toString();
        print(result);
      } else {
        print(error);
        result = {"error": error};
      }
    });
  }
}


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

you, probably, are using special characters in transaction id which phonepe doesn't allow.

No, i am not using special characters in transaction id

The error you're seeing, "INVALID_TRANSACTION_ID," means that the PhonePe SDK thinks the transaction ID you're using is not valid.
Make sure the transaction ID you're providing is correct and matches the expected format. It should correspond to a real transaction that has been properly processed.
IF your ID is right so please attach full code. So check deeply.
